# amazon aws server was working last night, not in the morning

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, config, telnet

I have an aws ec2 micro (free tier, so no tech support) and as is expected, when I got back in the morning my PuTTY had timed out from being connected for a few hours, this has happened multiple times before. When I went to restart the connection, I got a connection refusal. Tried more times, nothing. WinSCP, what I use for file transfer, also can't connect to a new login, but praise the lord allowed me to download all the files I had on the server. I tried on another device and through telnet on all the open incoming ports, connections refused. The MindTerm or whatever it's called when you click connect (on firefox) also couldn't connect.

The instance is all green, volume is all green, passing all status checks as well.

**I have looked at other threads, but they are for after a restart or changing of the ssh config. I haven't touched anything.** I doubt the permissions or anything have been compromised.

Comment: Probably better to find help on ServerFault - but if it's not a production box, reset the instance. It probably hit 100% CPU and can't process connections.

Comment: Agree with @brandonscript about ServerFault. Also, maybe your IP changed. Check the security group allowed incoming IPs for SSH. Maybe you had selected "My IP"?

Comment: for Brandon-> cpu credits are maxed out utilization from past 2 weeks  maxed at 2.33%
for Jedi-> all ports are unrestricted source 0.0.0.0/0. I also have not restarted my router, so I don't know how my ip would have changed, and even if it did, I have been connecting to this server for a month with no issues. Thanks for the responses though.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently just hitting reboot on the server did it. Can't believe I didn't think of something so easy.

Comment: If CPU credits were maxed out then that's only a temporary solution. You probably need to upgrade to a larger server type with more CPU credits, or a different type altogether that doesn't use credits.

Comment: to clarify, even though the thread is already answered, Maxed out meant it had stored the max of 150 or whatever it is, signifying that CPU overutilization was not the issue. Sorry for the confusion.